# How to set border, margin and padding on a PDF document using itext 7

Tags: java, itext, itext7

I am trying to set border, margin, and padding to a PDF document, is it possible to achieve using itext7

Margin works fine by setting below code

```
document.setLeftMargin(180);
```

But the border is not working, below code used to set the border

```
float width = 1.5f;
Color color = ColorConstants.BLUE;
Border border = new DottedBorder(color,width);
Document document = new Document(pdfDocument);
document.setBorder(border);
```

Comment: Below code used to set border to a document, but its not working.

    float width = 1.5f;
    Color color = ColorConstants.BLUE;
    Border border = new DottedBorder(color,width);
    Document document = new Document(pdfDocument);
    document.setBorder(border);

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately it's not possible to specify the document's background and borders just by setting some of the `Document`'s properties. The good news is that iText7 provides us with an opportunity to override `DocumentRenderer` (renderers are classes responsible to render corresponding model objects, for example, `ParagraphRenderer` renders `Paragraph` and so on).

In the custom `DocumentRenderer` below `updateCurrentArea` was overridden to tackle the following two issues:

- shrinking the area which will be used by `DocumentRenderer` to layout the `Document`'s children
- adding a background `Div`, whic will be resposible for border rendering (I've also shown how one could set background, if needed)

  ```
   class CustomDocumentRenderer extends DocumentRenderer {
   public CustomDocumentRenderer(Document document) {
       super(document);
   }

   @Override
   protected LayoutArea updateCurrentArea(LayoutResult overflowResult) {
       LayoutArea area = super.updateCurrentArea(overflowResult); // margins are applied on this level
       Rectangle newBBox = area.getBBox().clone();

       // apply border
       float[] borderWidths = {10, 10, 10, 10};
       newBBox.applyMargins(borderWidths[0], borderWidths[1], borderWidths[2], borderWidths[3], false);

       // this div will be added as a background
       Div div = new Div()
               .setWidth(newBBox.getWidth())
               .setHeight(newBBox.getHeight())
               .setBorder(new SolidBorder(10))
               .setBackgroundColor(ColorConstants.GREEN);
       addChild(new DivRenderer(div));

       // apply padding
       float[] paddingWidths = {20, 20, 20, 20};
       newBBox.applyMargins(paddingWidths[0], paddingWidths[1], paddingWidths[2], paddingWidths[3], false);

       return (currentArea = new RootLayoutArea(area.getPageNumber(), newBBox));
   }
  ```

  }

The last quetions is how to apply it on your document. It could be done as follows:

```
    PdfDocument pdfDoc = new PdfDocument(new PdfWriter(outFileName));
    Document doc = new Document(pdfDoc);
    doc.setRenderer(new CustomDocumentRenderer(doc));
```

The resultant PDF: [image]